# Sufficient and Necessary condition for the sum of brownian motions to be a brownian motion

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

The question has two parts :

Part a): Let $(B_1(t), B_2(t), B_3(t))$ be standard a brownian motion in $R^3$. Write down necassary and sufficient condition for $\sum\limits_{i=1}^3 a_iB_i(t)$ to be a one dimensional browian motion.

Here is my attempt : 
We have to make sure that the sum is gaussian with mean zero and variance $t$ (since the starting brownian motion is standard). 
Sum of gaussians is gaussian, also sum of 3 mean zero random variables has mean zero. 
For variance, $Var(\sum\limits_{i=1}^3 a_iB_i(t)) = a_1^2Var(B_1(t)) +a_2^2Var(B_2(t))+a_3^2Var(B_3(t))$ (since they are independent) we conclude that 
$\sum\limits_{i=1}^3 a_i = 1$ is sufficient and necassary.

What is the flaw in this reasoning? I was told that the above answer is not correct, however, I am unable to see why.

Part b) Suppose that $X(t)$ is a stochastic process with $X(0) = 0$ and,  continuous sample paths, and X(t) is normal mean $0$ and variance $t$. 
Prove or disprove : $X(t)$ is a brownian motion.

Here is my attempt : 
I think it just follows by Levy characterization right? or is there more to it ?

I appreciate help/hints/suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Why do you conclude $$\sum_{i=1}^3 a_i = 1?$$ Your calculation of the variance actually shows that $$\sum_{i=1}^3 a_i^2 = 1$$ is a necessary condition.
2. Lévy's characterization requires that the processes $(X_t,\mathcal{F}_t)_{t \geq 0}$ and $(X_t^2 -t, \mathcal{F}_t)_{t \geq 0}$ are martingales. This is not assumed here. 
   Think about the following process: Let $Y \sim N(0,1)$ be a centered Gaussian random variable with variance $1$ and define $$X_t := \sqrt{t} Y, \qquad t \geq 0.$$ Does $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ satisfy the given assumptions? Is it a Brownian motion?

Comment: Oh for parta I actually meant what you wrote I forgot the power 2. But is that sufficient as well?

Comment: For part 2) Ok so $X_t$ does satisfy the assumption but is not a brownian motion since it doesn't satisfy the independent increment property right?

Comment: @Alex Part a): I see. And yes, the condition is sufficient. Who told you that this is not correct? part b): Yes, exactly.

Comment: Thanks again!, well I heard it from some other students, now I just don't see why it would be wrong.